# Accessing the URL of a UIWebView in Swift 3

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift3

I am trying to access the URL of a UIWebView in Swift 3. Here is the code that I am using to accomplish this (the name of my webview is RootView):

`let currentURL : NSString = RootView.request?.URL?.absoluteString`

However, I get an error saying "Value of type 'URLRequest' has no member 'URL'" that prevents me from compiling. I know that previous stack overflow users have used this same line of code successfully, so I am not sure what is preventing me from also obtaining the URL. Could the problem lie in a change that Apple made to Swift 3? Thanks!

Here is my full ViewController.swift file where I put this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var RootView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.RootView.delegate = self
        let url1 = URL (string: "https://www.google.com")!
        RootView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url1))
        RootView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        RootView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let currentURL : NSString = RootView.request?.URL?.absoluteString
        print(currentURL)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Give more context. Such as the surrounding code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options to access the url

```
let currentURL : String? = RootView.request?.mainDocumentURL?.absoluteString
let currentURL : String? = RootView.request?.url?.absoluteString
let currenturl : String? = RootView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.location.href")
```

but all of these three values would return you `nil`, as request need time, they won't be ready until the request finished. Have a try.

```
import UIKit

class URLResearchVC: UIViewController , UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var RootView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.RootView.delegate = self
        let url1 = URL (string: "https://www.google.com")!
        RootView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url1))
        RootView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        RootView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let currentURL : String? = RootView.request?.mainDocumentURL?.absoluteString
        let currentUrl : String? = RootView.request?.url?.absoluteString
        let currenturl : String? = RootView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.location.href")
        print(currentURL)
        print(currentUrl)
        print(currenturl)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print("-------")
        print(webView.request?.mainDocumentURL)
        print("-------")
        print(webView.request?.url?.absoluteString)
        print("-------")
        print(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.location.href"))
    }
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print("-------")
        print(webView.request?.mainDocumentURL)
        print("-------")
        print(webView.request?.url?.absoluteString)
        print("-------")
        print(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "window.location.href"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! The webViewDidFinishLoad function works perfectly, and I am able to receive the URL of the page each time I navigate to a new website in the webview.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "request", and use following:

let currentURL : NSString = RootView.URL?.absoluteString